# In confluent-dotnet-kafka how to pass an object in Message Producer in .Net

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm working with .net core 3.1
and using the confluent kafka lib

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
```

And i'm implementing the kafka system, creating both producer and consumer.

I know i can easily do something like the code below to create and send messages to topics in the producer:

```
using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<long, string>(config).Build()) 
{
 for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
 {
  var deliveryReport = await producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<long, string> { Key 
 = i, Value = "lorem ipsum "+i });
 }
}
```

That works well.

But how can i do if i want to work with an object instead?
The following doesn't work:

```
using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<long, User>(config).Build()) 
{
 for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
 {
  var user = new User() { Id = i, Name = "random" }; 
  var deliveryReport = await producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<long, User> { Key 
 = i, Value = user });
 }
}
```

What is it missing? I heard there is a way of doing something similar but can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka accepts bytes in any client, not "objects". You will need to implement your own *serializer*, or use the ones that the Confluent Schema Registry supports.

JSON example - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/JsonSerialization

Avro example - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/AvroSpecific

Protobuf example - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Protobuf

Comment: Are these / or any of them, open source?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Github links are all open source. Did you open them?

Comment: yes @OneCricketeer i opened. Someone from my work, left me in doubt if these can be used for commercial use without a license.

Comment: I'd bet money you are already using some Apache software at your work. https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: I guess there is no problem then. I'm going to mark your answer as the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you would have to serialize your object. As far as I know, JSON payloads are outside of the scope of the library you've been using.

Therefore, you could possibly use Avro (but you will need Schema Registry). Here's an [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs):

```
using Avro;
using Avro.Generic;
using Confluent.Kafka.SyncOverAsync;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroGeneric
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: .. bootstrapServers schemaRegistryUrl topicName");
                return;
            }

            string bootstrapServers = args[0];
            string schemaRegistryUrl = args[1];
            string topicName = args[2];
            string groupName = "avro-generic-example-group";

            // var s = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(File.ReadAllText("my-schema.json"));
            var s = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(
                @"{
                    ""namespace"": ""Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroSpecific"",
                    ""type"": ""record"",
                    ""name"": ""User"",
                    ""fields"": [
                        {""name"": ""name"", ""type"": ""string""},
                        {""name"": ""favorite_number"",  ""type"": [""int"", ""null""]},
                        {""name"": ""favorite_color"", ""type"": [""string"", ""null""]}
                    ]
                  }"
            );

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var consumeTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = schemaRegistryUrl }))
                using (var consumer =
                    new ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ConsumerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers, GroupId = groupName })
                        .SetKeyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<string>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                        .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                        .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                        .Build())
                {
                    consumer.Subscribe(topicName);

                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);

                                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {consumeResult.Message.Key}\nValue: {consumeResult.Message.Value}");
                            }
                            catch (ConsumeException e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        // commit final offsets and leave the group.
                        consumer.Close();
                    }
                }
            });

            using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = schemaRegistryUrl }))
            using (var producer =
                new ProducerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers })
                    .SetKeySerializer(new AvroSerializer<string>(schemaRegistry))
                    .SetValueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry))
                    .Build())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on {topicName}. Enter user names, q to exit.");

                int i = 0;
                string text;
                while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
                {
                    var record = new GenericRecord(s);
                    record.Add("name", text);
                    record.Add("favorite_number", i++);
                    record.Add("favorite_color", "blue");

                    await producer
                        .ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, GenericRecord> { Key = text, Value = record })
                        .ContinueWith(task => task.IsFaulted
                            ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
                            : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                }
            }

            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON is not out of scope (see my answer). Is has always been in the same scope of Strings, because that is all the JSON is